# Why does the Web Scraper not fetch the data from this or similar websites?

Tags: java, html

I am trying to run this code for **scraping** Artist names for my research project but the code doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong and since I am an absolute beginner in Java I would be pleased to get help.

I am using JSoup and I am trying to get the Artist names from this Website: https://www.choon.co/playlists/genre_12-bar-blues/12-bar-blues and similar Websites. Every time I run the Code I don't get any failure notice it just says: "Fetching...", "Done!". But nothing in between. I tried it with every Class possible but this seems not to be the problem.

I would be pleased to get some help.

```
 package com.manu.scraper;
 
 import java.io.IOException;
 
 import org.jsoup.Jsoup; import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; import
 org.jsoup.nodes.Element; import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
 
 
 
 public class Spider {   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Fetching...");
                try {           Document doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.choon.co/playlists/genre_12-bar-blues/12-bar-blues").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0
 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
 Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36").get();
        
                        Elements temp=doc.select("class.ch-track-list__cell"); 
                        int i=0;            for(Element artistList:temp)            {
                i++;
                System.out.println(i+ " " + artistList.getElementsByTag("a").first().text() );              }
            System.out.println("Done!");        } 
        
    
                catch (IOException e) {             // TODO Auto-generated catch block          e.printStackTrace();        }
        
        
            }   }
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a total beginner move. :)

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {             // TODO Auto-generated catch block          e.printStackTrace();        }` Is that all a single code line, as shown above? If so, the important `e.printStackTrace();` is commented out. General tips: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason Jsoup doesn't detect any HTML elements is because the elements on the page are rendered dynamically using JS. Jsoup is an HTML parser and will parse the page's HTML and allow you to select the elements you want. However, if you look at the source for the page you are requesting you will see that the elements you are selecting do not exist and that it mostly and empty HTML shell. The content you see in the browser is added to the DOM dynamically, not in the source HTML it self.

Comment: Thanks tantalum for the answer and for everyone else it’s not one line but I didn’t know how to put it proper inside my question. So what would you recommend then? Is there another opportunity or solution to fetch the data besides Jsoup? Thanks in advance for your answer :)